# Regex - allow characters unless a certain character precedes part of the string?

Tags: c#, regex

I don't know if this is even possible with regex, but here's the scenario. The strings I'm matching against are space-separated lists (HTML classes). Strings should be matched if each word uses lowercase a-z, spaces, and/or 0-9, unless the word starts with @.

Ideal results:

`red-one green-two blue-three` = matched
`redOne green-two blue-three` = not matched (found a capital letter)
`red-one blue-two @greenThree` = matched (found a capital letter, but the word started with @)

Any ideas? I'm thinking it's not possible, but maybe a guru knows.

Comment: If you post what you tried and why it did not work, it would clarify what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following expression to handle that scenario which will essentially handle matching at the "word" level and just ensure that each word has an optional trailing space (to handle it being space delimited) :

```
^((@[a-zA-Z-]+|([a-z-])+)\s?)+$
```

This basically consists of two major conditions :

- **`@[a-zA-Z-]+`**

  - This section will allow a single set of characters to contain uppercase letters *if* it begins with an '@' character.
- **`[a-z-])+`**

  - This section is your "normal" use case, which will only match a series of characters that contain lowercase and hyphens.

Both of these conditions allow for an optional trailing space character after each set, which will allow each "word" within your lists to be evaluated on its own.

**Example**

[image]

```
var tests = new []{ 
    "red-one green-two blue-three", 
    "redOne green-two blue-three",
    "red-one blue-two @greenThree"
};

foreach(var test in tests)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^((@[a-zA-Z-]+|([a-z-])+)\s?)+$");
    Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(test));
}
```